# Replace foreign characters with latin counterparts, and spaces with hyphens (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I have this code:

```
$header = 'weird character->>>ÅÅÖÄ';
$header = strtolower(str_replace(array('  ', ' '), '-', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 s]/', '', trim($header))));
```

It should output `weird-characteraaoa`, but it doesn't. It just removes the ÅÅÖÄ-letters. Any idea why this isn't working? I'm using UTF-8 if that has something to do with it

Comment: Don't do it like that, you need to convert it first, use `iconv` http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

Comment: Why does your `[^a-zA-Z0-9 s]` have an `s` at the end? The `s` won't do anything, did you mean `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard problem since not all languages can match-up well with ASCII characters.

However, @AlixAxel has the current best implementation I've ever seen in his [phunction framework](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction/Text.php#L249).

```
    public static function Slug($string, $slug = '-', $extra = null)
    {
        return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z' . preg_quote($extra, '~') . ']+~i', $slug, self::Unaccent($string)), $slug));
    }

    public static function Unaccent($string)
    {
        if (extension_loaded('intl') === true)
        {
            $string = Normalizer::normalize($string, Normalizer::FORM_KD);
        }

        if (strpos($string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '&') !== false)
        {
            $string = html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|caron|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $string), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }

        return $string;
    }
```

Comment: I've included the whole document, any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: Yes, download phunction and use it. You can also take those two functions and put them in a class called `i18n` or  `string` and call it like `$slug = String::slug('ÅÅÖÄ');`

Comment: This works fine. Do I really need the whole phunction.php and phunction_Text files? Or do I only need the snippet you posted? Cheers

Comment: @AlbinN, you know how to [make a class](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) in PHP right?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to create a custom function as below and use it:

```
function normalize ($string) {
   $table = array('Å'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A','Ö'=>'O');
   return strtr($string, $table);
}
```

Please add the chars you want to use.

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands of characters in unicode. This approach is not realistic unless you have several months to compile a list.

Comment: @Xeoncross: My answer was specific to the string in example and for few characters, its simple.